# squid:S2583 : Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true"

Tags: java, sonarlint

S2583: How can the condition `ps != null` be changed so that it does not always evaluate to "false"?

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
if (ps != null) {
  try {
    ps.close();
  } catch (SQLException uncatched) {
     uncatched.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're actually asking here. You set a variable equal to null and the check if it is not null. This will always return false because in this code example there is no way that ps can be anything but null.

Comment: sorry actually i left few lines that will add some values to ps then the below  conditions will get executed                                                                                         my concern is why sonarlint is giving such a warning in blocker category

Comment: Then please update your code to reflect the real situation. In its current state, the presence of this `if` statement is misleading and reveals that you might have forgotten to do anything useful with `ps`, which is exactly why it's blocker. Just remove the `if` altogether if it's dead code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if ps is not null because you always set a value to it (at lines that you omitted), the conditional statement is completely redundant and you can eliminate the condition.

From squid:S2583 description:

> Conditional statements using a condition which cannot be anything but
>   FALSE have the effect of making blocks of code non-functional. If the
>   condition cannot evaluate to anything but TRUE, the conditional
>   statement is completely redundant, and makes the code less readable.